# Finding the probability of picking a certain ball

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I haven't studied any probability for a while now (around five years, to be precise). So, I decided to just throw in the following question here.

A box contains  $b$ blue balls and $y$ yellow balls. One ball is drawn at random from the box, but is then put back into the box with $a$ additional balls of the same colour. Another ball is now drawn at random from the box. What is the probability that the first ball drawn was blue, given that the second ball drawn is yellow (in terms of $b, y, a$)?

Comment: OK, you may be rusty, but protocol dictates that you first put down whatever rusty efforts you have made.

Comment: If a box contains $b$ blue balls and $y$ yellow balls, then probability of drawing a blue ball does not depend on what you have seen or will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a shot, though fair warning, I am also rusty.

So we want $$P(\text{first ball = blue} | \text{second ball = yellow})$$
By Bayes theorem,
$$P(\text{first ball = blue} | \text{second ball = yellow}) = \frac{ P(\text{second ball = yellow} | \text{first ball = blue}) P(\text{first ball = blue})} {P(\text{second ball = yellow})} $$

Let's find the factors in the numerator first:
$$P(\text{first ball = blue}) = \frac{b}{y + b} $$

$$P(\text{second ball = yellow} | \text{first ball = blue}) = \frac{y}{(b + a) + y} $$

The first equation comes from the fact that we are selecting a ball at random. The second comes from the addition of a blue balls once we have selected the first ball as blue.

Now looking for the denominator:
$$P(\text{second ball = yellow}) = P(\text{second ball = yellow} | \text{first ball = blue}) P (\text{first ball = blue}) + P(\text{second ball = yellow} | \text{first ball = yellow}) P (\text{first ball = yellow})$$ Which follows from the Law of Total Probability.

Solving for that
$$P(\text{second ball = yellow}) = \frac{y}{(b + a) + y}\frac{b}{y + b} +\frac{y + a}{b + (y + a)} \frac{y}{y + b}$$

Putting it all together in Bayes' theorem I think you'll find that:

$$P(\text{first ball = blue} | \text{second ball = yellow}) = \frac{by}{by + y(y+a)}$$

At least, I hope that's right... I make no guarantees :-)

Comment: Thanks, @BigBear... This is a nice solution; thanks for helping. I was so rusty I didn't even bother trying. You are a bigger bear than you call yourself!